# selecting the values of two columns of a single row into a new dataframe using do.call function

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has three columns(time, Z Value, DT_Prediction). using the mode function to the third column, I am trying to find the corresponding time and z value.

```
my data <-
Time        Z Value      DT_Prediction
0.056       140.9476           S
0.242       139.4866           S
0.416       139.2088           S
0.596       140.68719          S
0.789       140.52847          S
0.956       139.32829          S
1.145       140.42706          T  
1.351       141.52762          T
1.498       140.57858          T
1.749       139.41685          T
1.858       140.26314          T
2.037       141.31653          T
2.249       140.4565           T 
2.399       139.49387          T 
2.578       140.44995          T
2.776       141.23109          T
2.939       140.29509          S
3.126       139.89639          S
3.338       140.88934          S
3.479       141.0612           S
3.7         140.17706          S
3.84        139.67476          S
```

for this, I am trying with the following code....here in the code I am using a window size of 8

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

bharat <- do.call(rbind, 
              lapply(split(mydata, (0:nrow(mydata) %/% 8)), function(i)
                data.frame(Starting_Time = i[1,1], 
                           Ending_Time = i[nrow(i),1], 
                           Starting_ZValue = i[1,2],
                           Ending_ZValue = i[nrow(i),2],
                           mode = getmode(i[[3]]))))

library(data.table)
New <- setDT(bharat)[, .(mode = mode[1], Starting_Time = Starting_Time[1],
                     Ending_Time = Ending_Time[.N]), Starting_ZValue = 
Starting_ZValue[2], Ending_ZValue = Ending_ZValue[.N], by = .(rleid(mode))]
```

i am getting the result as follows

```
mode      Statring_Time      Ending_Time
 S          0.056                1.351  
 T          1.498                2.776
 S          2.939                3.84
```

but the code was written to get the result as follows

```
mode      Statring_Time      Ending_Time   Starting_ZValue   Ending_Value
 S          0.056                1.351        140.9476           141.52762 
 T          1.498                2.776        140.57858          141.23109
 S          2.939                3.84         140.29509          139.67476
```

there is some mistake in the code that I am unable to correct it

thanks in advance

Comment: I get the desired result (one at the bottom with five columns) simply executing the code you have.

Comment: I am not getting with the code I mentioned .... I don't know.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do using the `tidyverse` suite of packages, if you want an alternate solution.  I made a slightly different data set to test it on.

```
df <- data_frame(
  time = sort(runif(20)),
  z_value = rnorm(20, 140),
  DT_pred = rep(c("S", "T", "S"), c(6, 8, 6))
)

result <- df %>%
  mutate(
    new_DT = !(DT_pred == c("0", DT_pred[-length(DT_pred)])),
    group = cumsum(new_DT)
  ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(
    n = n(),
    mode = DT_pred[1],
    start_time = time[1],
    end_time = time[n],
    start_Zvalue = z_value[1],
    end_Zvalue = z_value[n],
  )
```

If you're not familiar with the pipe operator (%>%), it passes the result of the previous function as the first argument of the next function.  It makes code easier to read.  You can see what this is doing by calling pieces of it, e.g.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    new_DT = !(DT_pred == c("0", DT_pred[-length(DT_pred)])),
    group = cumsum(new_DT)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
fac=head(c(0,1:nrow(data)%/%8),-1)

do.call(rbind,by(data,fac,function(x)cbind(x[1,],tail(x,1))))[c(3,1,4,2,5)]
  DT_Prediction  Time Time.1  Z_Value Z_Value.1
0             S 0.056  1.351 140.9476  141.5276
1             T 1.498  2.776 140.5786  141.2311
2             S 2.939  3.840 140.2951  139.6748
```